# Remove HEADERS from crawl

Tags: java, web-crawler, stormcrawler

Working on Storm Crawler 1.13 and Elastic Search 6.5.2. Working in TextExtractor. I am excluding **script** and **style** tags similarly I want to remove **header** tags. I am applying below configuration but its not applying to all results.  I want to keep **h1** , **h2** , **h3** only remove **header** named tags. Any Suggestions.

**Webpage**:

```
<header id="section-header" class="section section-header">
</header>

<h1 class="title" id="page-title">Good Morning..</h1>
```

**crawlerconf.yaml**

```
  textextractor.include.pattern:
   - DIV[id="maincontent"]
   - DIV[itemprop="articleBody"]
   - ARTICLE

  textextractor.exclude.tags:
   - STYLE
   - SCRIPT
   - HEADER
   - FOOTER
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not reproduce your issue on my local machine. It may be a configuration flaw on your side or the websites you referring to are special.

Did you verify, that your custom `crawler-conf.yaml` is properly loaded and the `textextractor.exclude.tags` are included in the loaded configuration?

I did the following steps trying to reproduce your question:

1. I checked out the `1.13` release sources of StormCrawler.
2. I added the following unit test to `TextExtractorTest.java`:

```
    @Test
    public void testRemoveHeaderElements() throws IOException {
        Config conf = new Config();
        HashSet<String> excluded = new HashSet<>();
        excluded.add("HEADER");
        excluded.add("FOOTER");
        excluded.add("SCRIPT");
        excluded.add("STYLE");
        conf.put(TextExtractor.EXCLUDE_PARAM_NAME, PersistentVector.create(excluded));

    HashSet&lt;String&gt; included = new HashSet&lt;&gt;();
    included.add("DIV[id=\"maincontent\"]");
    included.add("DIV[itemprop=\"articleBody\"]");
    included.add("ARTICLE");
    conf.put(TextExtractor.INCLUDE_PARAM_NAME, PersistentVector.create(included));

    TextExtractor extractor = new TextExtractor(conf);

    String content = "&lt;header id=\"section-header\" class=\"section section-header\"&gt;&lt;/header&gt;&lt;h1 class=\"title\" id=\"page-title\"&gt;Good Morning..&lt;/h1&gt;";

    Document jsoupDoc = Parser.htmlParser().parseInput(content,
            "http://stormcrawler.net");
    String text = extractor.text(jsoupDoc.body());

    assertEquals("Good Morning..", text);
}
```

This unit test on the `TextExtractor` component passes. Next, I did upload a website with the following HTML code to a local deployed web server:

```
<header id="section-header" class="section section-header">
</header>



Good Morning..
```

The extracted text content is: `Good Morning..`, which should be fine according to your requirements.